# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

I try to use pytorch module by conda but I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 8, in <module>
import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

when I write `conda list | findstr torch` I see that torch is installed:

[image]
What is the problem?

I tried:

```
conda update conda -n root
conda install mkl=2018
```

but get:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

Could Not Find C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\conda-23721-26470.tmp
Could Not Find C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\tmpry_dlvar.bat
```

and the same error occurrence

Comment: did you activate conda environment ?

Comment: yes, I activate conda environment.
`conda activate faster`

Comment: Alright, which IDE are you using?

Comment: I don't use IDE, I run the program by command line

Comment: Side note: `conda list torch` will automatically apply a regex filter, so need for an extra pipe.

Comment: did you get it running?

Comment: FWIW, restarting the terminal session kicked things into gear for me

Answer (score 1):

Try the below mentioned one, surely  it will work.

conda install -c pytorch pytorch

Comment: thanks but is not working, I get the same module not found error

Comment: What IDE you are using to compile your program? Spyder or anything else. Please mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the following on the local environment as given in the pytorch website during installation. Open Jupyter Notebook locally and run the following

```
from __future__ import print_function
import torch
x = torch.rand(5, 3)
print(x)
```

if this works then most likely the environment variable is not set properly.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The command runs properly but when in VS code, I still get the ModuleNotFound error when doing `import torch`